# Redirecting button after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, redirect

I have two buttons (describing the type of delivery). Once selected I have to press another button to proceed . Is there any way how I can proceed automatically after selection?

Here is my code before selection:

```
<button type="button" class="button btn-delivery-method" data-delivery-method="s_method_free">
    <span class="btn-delivery-method__label">Select</span>
</button>
```

Here is my code after selection:

```
<button type="button" class="button btn-delivery-method delivery-method__selected" data-delivery-method="s_method_free">
    <span class="btn-delivery-method__label">Select</span>
</button>
```

Here is my third button to proceed:

```
<button type="button" class="button btn-large--alt" onclick="shippingMethod.save()">    
    Continue    
</button>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the onclick event to the first two buttons.

Btw, what does the code do after pressing either of the first two buttons?

Comment: once you select it is changing the button to selected but the problem is once I add onClick event in first case which is the not selected option button does not allow me to save it. It is asking me for shipping method

Comment: mohamedrias answer is how you ideally do it in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click event to the first button as well:

```
$(".button.btn-delivery-method").click(function() {

   // check if the delivery has been selected
   if($(this).hasClass("delivery-method__selected")) {
      // either call shippigMethod.save(); here

      //trigger the button click
      $(".button.btn-large--alt").trigger("click");
   }
});
```

This will trigger the button only when the delivery is selected

```
if($(this).hasClass("delivery-method__selected")) {
     $(".button.btn-large--alt").trigger("click");
 }
```

Comment: can you please implement in in example with the html code? I am sorry if this sounds lame

Comment: I have just checked it. It works and it is great but what I actually want to do is to avoid having second button. So lets say we have to delivery options once the wanted one is selected I want the same button which change it property from   ****class="button btn-delivery-method"**** to ****class="button btn-delivery-method delivery-method__selected"*** to automatically redirect to lets say ****onclick="shippingMethod.save()"*** Do you think this is possible?

Comment: yes sure. Check this : http://jsbin.com/qacovagovo/1/edit?html,css,js,output you need to call `shippingMethod.save()` inside the button click

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have the Id from your second button just to avoid any conflicts with other buttons.